# How to paste formula from a row to the bottom of a range on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with a range of data in B:C, starting at B30 that extends to a dynamic number of rows.

There is a formula in E1:O1.

I wish to copy the formula from E1:O1 and paste it in the range next to the data in B:C (leaving column D blank).

I have been editing some code from here and it works for the most part,  however when it copies the formula from the top of the sheets it only pastes it in the top row.

My edited code:

```vb
'move data data and populate formulas

'for New
Sub Copy()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s3 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s4 As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
    Dim iLastCellS3 As Excel.Range
    Dim iLastCellS4 As Excel.Range
    
    Dim idataRange1 As Excel.Range
    Dim idataRange2 As Excel.Range
    Dim idataRange3 As Excel.Range
    
    Dim iLastRowS1 As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("SET UP")
    Set s2 = Sheets("New")
    Set s3 = Sheets("Current")
    Set s4 = Sheets("Proposed")

    ' get last row number of C in SET UP
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into new for data data
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into current for data data
    Set iLastCellS3 = s3.Cells(s3.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into proposed for data data
    Set iLastCellS4 = s4.Cells(s4.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
    
    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into new for formula
    Set idataRange1 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
    
    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into current for formula
    Set idataRange2 = s3.Cells(s3.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 3)
    
    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into proposed for formula
    Set idataRange3 = s4.Cells(s4.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 3)

    'copy&paste into New
    s1.Range("C17", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "D")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    'copy&paste formulas for new
    s2.Range("E1:O1").Copy idataRange1
    
    'copy&paste into Current
    s1.Range("C17", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "D")).Copy iLastCellS3
        
    'copy&paste formulas for Current
    s3.Range("E1:O1").Copy idataRange2
        
    'copy&paste into Proposed
    s1.Range("C17", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "D")).Copy iLastCellS4
        
    'copy&paste formulas for proposed
    s4.Range("E1:AU1").Copy idataRange3
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Each section with the "'copy&paste formulas for" is only pasting into the top row of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Data and Formulas

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyDataAndFormulas()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "SET UP"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "C17"
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "C:D"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "B"
 
    Dim dwsNames(): dwsNames = VBA.Array("New", "Current", "Proposed")
    Dim dfAddresses(): dfAddresses = VBA.Array("E1:O1", "E1:O1", "E1:AU1")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        srCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data in source worksheet.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount).EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS)
        scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, dfCell As Range, n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(dwsNames)
        Set dws = wb.Sheets(dwsNames(n))
        Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srCount, scCount)
        srg.Copy drg
        ' or to copy only values:
        'drg.Value = srg.Value
        With dws.Range(dfAddresses(n))
            .Copy Intersect(drg.EntireRow, .EntireColumn)
        End With
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data and formulas copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to copy from s1 to s2:

```
s1.Range("E:O").Copy s2.Range("E:O")
```

Comment: I wish to copy the formula from E1:O1 on S2 from D30 to the bottom of the last row in B:C.